# diffence between <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> and <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

Tags: spring

What is the difference between / and /* in web.xml ?

for the dispatcher servlet / is used and i guess this means all the requests.In that case what does url-pattern "/*" means ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/*` means "all requests", whereas `/` means "all requests not handled by other servlets".

In particular, a common source of confusion is that `/*` overrides mappings of built-in servlets, such as JSP servlet. It means that if you map `DispatcherServlet` to `/*`, you won't be able to use JSP-based views, because requests to render these views will be handler by `DispatcherServlet` itself rather than by JSP servlet that actually renders JSP pages.

That's why `DispatcherServlet` that should handle all requests is usually mapped to `/`.

Comment: Thanks :) One more thing by all request you mean all the child paths are included or not ?

Answer (score 2):

from [SRV.11.2 Specification of Mappings](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7840-servlet-2.3-spec-oth-JSpec/)

> In the web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ postfix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>     request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

The pattern `/*` will force everything through your servlet. The pattern `/` will make your servlet the default servlet for the app, meaning it will pick up every pattern that doesn't have another exact match